# Using "just" and "just now"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Is it correct to say for sure that we use "just" with Present Perfect and "just now" with Past Simple and it's incorrect to do it vice versa?
For example:

1. I've just done it.
2. I did it just now.

Answer (score 2):

> I've **just** done it.
>   I did it **just now**.

Those are both correct. However...

> I've **just now** done it.
>   I've done it **just now**.
>   I **just** did it.

Those are also correct<sup>1</sup>. What isn't correct:

> I've done it just.
>   I did it just.

You can't use ***just*** alone in that position *after* the subject. That has to be ***just now***. However:

> I've done it, just.
>   I did it, just.

Those are fine, but have a different meaning, at least in the dialects I am most familiar with - *just* in that case has the meaning of *barely*. The other cases of *just* without *now* can also have that meaning, though it would be differentiated from the *very recently* sense by stress or context. Navigating dialects never being straightforward, I am informed that this use of *just* can also mean the same as *just now* in at least one regional dialect of British English.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Which is more natural or conventional is heavily dependent on dialect, and I don't just mean American English vs British English - regional dialects play a big part.

Comment: In the West Midlands of England, both "I've done it, just" and "I did it, just" are very common. I have not heard this in any other version of English.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Is that to mean the same as "just now", or "barely"? I've heard it used a fair amount in several regional dialects to mean "barely", but never to mean "just now" (though not conversed with people from the west midlands much - and those I have are educated in the way that means they avoid dialectal words and phrasing).

Comment: No, it means "just now". I spent much of my life there. Example: "Have you cleared up your room?", "Yes, I did it just". (i.e. "I did it just now")

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'll edit to take account of that, thanks.