# Having deal with "to get used to" and "to be used to"

Tags: progressive-aspect, perfect-aspect, perfect-continuous

I know "to get used to" means the process of accustoming whereas "to be used to" means that somebody has done it, this process is finished and now there is nothing unusual connected with this thing, it has become familiar to the person.

While I was reading an article about those construction I found out we could use both constructions in different tenses. But I was wodering is there any sense in using "to get used to" in any tense we would like to do it?

Once it means the process so we are able to use it in any tense, but, as for the "to be used to" construction? As we've stated above, it is the result, so possible variants are:

1. Present/Past/Future Simple;
2. Present/Past/Future Perfect;

And, at least, it's awkward and unlogical to use it with Progressive and Perfect Progressive forms. Am I right?

Would you be so kind as to provide me some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't say

> I **am|was being used to** the incessant rain. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> I **have been being used to** the incessant rain.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

But we do say

> I am|was **getting used to** the incessant rain.
>
> I **have|had been getting used to** the incessant rain.
>
> I'm staying with my brother this summer. I expect **I will be getting used to** his spicy cooking after a month or so. In July, his wife is returning after visiting her parents in Iceland. I **will** just **have been getting used to** his spicy cooking when the meals will change dramatically.

Comment: So, I've done a correct assumption. Thank you. And could I ask you to view an another topic of mine: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123570/using-just-and-just-now